# WPF How to open a form in WindowFormHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mdi

I am new to WPF, anybody can tell how to open a form inside WindowFormsHosting or any other way to create an mdi in WPF. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WPF has no inbuilt mdi feature, Did u try this third party component? https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Arul, I try it but the designer shows the error and run perfectly. I am not able to add more controls in it. Is there is another way ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with

[WPFMdi](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) classic mdi window manager

[Avalondock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) supports separate tab sets and tear off windows